# Angular mat form field appearance

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do I implement this in Angular 12?

below is the code in my html:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 70px;"
  [appearance]="somevariable ? 'none' : 'legacy'"
>
  <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" 
    [readonly]="VOForm.get('VORows').value[i].isEditable" 
  />
</mat-form-field>
```

Here the appearance attribute doesn't take the value "none" since `"strictTemplates": true` under `angularCompilerOptions`.

What is the workaround, I still want to use Mat-form-field ?

My use case is , when `somevariable` is true no appearance need to be applied but if the value is false then legacy appearance is applied.

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oe7ysu-mffz7l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html

Comment: make it a function like suggested in previous post it should work !

Comment: if you want leave as default you should use null: `[appearance]="somevariable ?null : 'legacy'"`, so is like you has no indicate the appearance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following class :

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline{
   display: none;}
```

The underline is always going to be hidden but you can apply this style conditionally with the use of ngClass. So in the template you have :

```
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="{'nameOfYourClass': expression">
</mat-form-field>
```

Where 'expression' is any expression returning a boolean.

And in the css :

```
::ng-deep .nameOfYourClass .mat-form-field-underline: {
   display: none;}
```

Had the same problem and it works for me! I hope it will work for you as well.

Cheers

Comment: FYI ::ng-deep is deprecated and will be removed.